# Is there another way to determine website user than by IP?

Tags: web-applications, web

In my website i need to remember users that entered so next time thay enter i will show them content they were checking before.
Simplest way is IP check, but problem appears if there is a proxy. I dont want to run any java scripts on client side to get their ip.
Is there any way to determine user?
I know that also profiles - login would do, but i dont want to do so.

Thanks in advance,
Marek.

Comment: have you considered using cookies to uniquely identify your users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set a persistent cookie, but that will just remain for that specific browser.  (and they could clear their cookies)

The most reliable way is to have your users log in with a username and password - then you can keep details specific to them in a database and modify the site's behaviour like you mention next time they log in.  However, this option doesn't work for anonymous visitors.

Comment: Thanks for your fast replay. I know cookie is standard way to perform this kind of job, but as mentioned they may be deleted or disabled. I was wandering if there is any other way to do it. I think i have no other option than to use cookies.

Comment: Yes, for anonymous users cookies are the way to go - not ideal in terms of reliability, but I guess website users need some amount of privacy ;)

Answer (score 0):

Consider setting a Cookie, which you can subsequently read and tailor content.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are what you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to remember users is setting a cookie. IP is totally ineffective, because many customery have dynamic IP addresses, let alone NAT. The way to set a cookie depends on the server language you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Using a cookie could identify the user per browser per computer.

Answer (score 0):

Marek, by default my recomendation would be to use cookies. Maybe record some ID in the cookie after the user loged in and use it to display custom content. 
Of course the user can always delete the cookie (or disable them all together), but it is a good solution for this kind of requirement.